# Why does my whole page move when I change margin-top?

Tags: css, html

Alright, I am making this website, from a tutorial, yes I am still a beginner, no the tutorial did not explain why this things happens.

Basically, this is what happens, I have the CSS like this.

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
body { font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }  

.container 
{  
    width: 800px;  
    margin: 0 auto;   
}  

body, div, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ul, img {margin:0px; padding:0px; }  

#main   
{
    background: url(images/header.jpg) repeat-x;
}

#main .container
{
    background: url(images/shine_04.jpg) no-repeat;
}

#logo 
{  
    background: url(images/logo.png) no-repeat;  
    height:104px;
    width:301px;
}  

#logo h1
{
    text-indent: -9999px;
    margin-top: 40px;
}
```

And my HTML like this, I only post the body.

```
 <div id="main">  
    <div class="container">
     <div id="header">  
       <div id="logo">  
         <h1>Logo</h1>
        </div>  
       <div id="tagline">  
         <h3>I Love Stuff</h3> 
        </div>
       <ul id="menu">  
         <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>  
         <li><a href="#">About</a></li>  
         <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>  
         <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>  
       </ul>  
     </div><!--end header -->  

     <div id="content">  
     <h2>Lorem ipsum, Dolor sit</h2>  
        <h3>Nullam vulputate felis id odio interdum nec malesuada mi pretium. </h3>  
        <p>Praesent luctus egestas nisl, vitae vehicula eros rhoncus vel.   
            Phasellus consequat arcu eu neque convallis eu vulputate diam vehicula. In eget venenatis nisl.   
            Vestibulum id nulla eu sapien pellentesque malesuada pharetra ac lacus.   
            Curabitur et ultricies quam. Aenean pretium aliquet velit, gravida vulputate urna tempus vel.  </p>  
        <p>Proin tempor erat sit amet nisl porta nec vulputate arcu imperdiet. Praesent luctus egestas nisl, vitae vehicula eros rhoncus vel.   
            Phasellus consequat arcu eu neque convallis eu vulputate diam vehicula. In eget venenatis nisl.   
            Vestibulum id nulla eu sapien pellentesque malesuada pharetra ac lacus. Curabitur et ultricies quam. Aenean pretium aliquet velit,   
        gravida vulputate urna tempus vel. Proin tempor erat sit amet nisl porta nec vulputate arcu imperdiet. </p>  
    <div id="news">  
        <h3>Latest Updates</h3>  
        <h4>Vestibulum id nulla eu sapien pellentesque</h4>  
        <small>June 1, 2009</small>  
        <p>Ut vel turpis a orci pulvinar tincidunt. Mauris id purus turpis. Aliquam metus arcu,   
            facilisis quis pellentesque vitae, dapibus non nulla. Nulla suscipit sagittis sodales.   
            Etiam laoreet ante in purus laoreet id malesuada dui pretium.<a href="#"> Read More</a></p>  
    <h4>Vestibulum id nulla eu sapien pellentesque</h4>  
    <small>June 1, 2009</small>  
    <p>Ut vel turpis a orci pulvinar tincidunt. Mauris id purus turpis. Aliquam metus arcu,   
        facilisis quis pellentesque vitae, dapibus non nulla. Nulla suscipit sagittis sodales.   
        Etiam laoreet ante in purus laoreet id malesuada dui pretium.<a href="#"> Read More</a></p>  
     </div><!--end news-->  

     </div><!--end content-->  

     <div id="sidebar">  
     <div id="subscribe">  
                    <h3>Subscribe!</h3>  
                    <ul>  
                        <li><a href="#">Subscribe via RSS</a></li>  
                        <li><a href="#">Get Email Updates</a></li>  
                        <li><a href="#">Follow us on Twitter</a></li>  
                    </ul>  
                </div>  
                <div id="popular">  
                    <h3>Popular Items</h3>  
                    <ul>  
                        <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor site amet</a></li>  
                        <li><a href="#">Ulvinar tincidunt, Mauris id</a></li>  
                        <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor site amet</a></li>  
                        <li><a href="#">Proin tempor erat sit tene</a></li>  
                    </ul>  
                </div>  
                <div id="contributors">  
                    <h3>Contributors</h3>  
                    <ul>  
                        <li><a href="#">John Smith, freelance writer</a></li>  
                        <li><a href="#">Jack McCoy, designer</a></li>  
                        <li><a href="#">Lenny Briscoe, editor</a></li>  
                        <li><a href="#">John Smith, martketing</a></li>  
                    </ul>  
                    <a href="#">Join Our Team</a>   
                </div>  



     </div><!--end sidebar-->  

    </div><!--end main container-->  
   </div><!--end main--> 


    <div id="footer">  
     <div class="container">  
          <p>Copyright © 2009  MySite <br />  
            All Rights Reserved</p>  
     </div><!--end footer container-->   

    </div><!--end footer-->
```

In the CSS, I have the `#logo` h1 selector, as you can see from the parent `#logo` selector, I have a background, which is exactly the logo, now I want the damn logo to be positioned 40px slightly lower from the top, that's why I put `margin-top: 40px;` , and I don't understand why, but instead of just the logo moving 40px down, the whole page moves down! T_T, I have already spent almost 1 hour trying to deduce all the logic that my brain can handle behind this, but I just cant!

And my question is just like what I said, why does the whole page move downwards? the logo image is the only element that's supposed to move, but why the whole thing? and what do I do to fix it?

Comment: A word of advice in such situations: Always use Firebug (or Chromebug, or any similar tool) to see what is going on. It helps me an awful lot in dealing with CSS issues... You can even change the values on the fly, and as I'm not much of an experienced CSS guy, I usually tune the CSS that way until it fits...

Comment: try to give padding-top:40px for logo...

Comment: But I use dreamweaver, and It doesn't give me any indications of problems, because basically, this is a logical error, and not a syntax error.

Comment: Try already giving padding top, but what happens is the "logo" text that I set 9000 for the z-index only goes down 40px, and not the image.

Comment: Open the page in a browser. Then use Firebug, and see what's going on... (Actually, apart from Word 97 (oh, boy, was I naive to try that), I never used any HTML editors, so there might be better tools around...)

Comment: I used chrome and firefox, nothing, everything is right and wrong at the same time.

Comment: And did you open [**firebug**](http://getfirebug.com/)? Did you look at what is going on? Did you try altering the CSS values within Firebug to see what changes? Do you actually know what firebug is?

Comment: Sorry, no :( , but I think dreamweaver has the features that firebug offers, that's why I don't use it. :)

Answer (score 3):

Try substituting margin with padding: `padding-top: 40px` on the parent container, i.e. `#header`, since you have specified a background image for `#logo` and do not have to see it move.

Why paddings over margins? It's simple: margins have the propensity to collapse. W3C has a [comprehensive section](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins) dedicated to rules that govern margin collapse.

p/s: For the ease of troubleshooting, try posting your issue on JSFiddle. Not only does it help the community to visualize your problem, but it also aids to expedit the process of actually solving your problem.

Comment: No luck, just the same result, the "LOGO" text moves down 40px, and not the image.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
#logo 
{  
    background: url(images/logo.png) no-repeat;  
    height:104px;
    width:301px;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-position: 0px 40px;
}
```

Comment: it works, but it's weird, it overlaps with the other elements, especially the list, it's supposed to be a block element.

Comment: I updated, should only move the image now instead of the whole div

Comment: But it overlaps with the other elements.

Comment: If your image is 104px high, then it is either going to push all elements on the page down or overlap. Unless you want to cut off the bottom of the image, in which case you should use `overflow: hidden;` inside the `#logo` element of your css.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
#logo {  
  background: url(images/logo.png) no-repeat;
  background-position: 0px 40px;
  height: 144px;
  width: 301px;
}
```

Comment: Again, it overlaps the other elements, especially the lists.

Comment: i have increased height as well if you missed that.